# Please help me .I want get data from sql server 

Tags: android

```
    Connection conn = null;
        String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.1.25:1433/";
        String dbName = "Demo;Instance=MSSQLSERVER;";
        String userName = "BIT"; 
        String password = "1234";
        String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
        try {
          TextView  tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
          TextView  tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
          TextView  tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
          Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
          conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);
          Log.w("Connection","open");
          Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
          ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT ItemDesc,Qty,NetPrice FROM TrxDetail ");
          String a ="";
      String b ="";
      String c ="";

      while (rs.next()) 
      {
           a += rs.getString("ItemDesc");
           b += rs.getString("Qty");
           c += rs.getString("NetPrice");
     }
      tv1.setText(a);
      tv2.setText(b);
      tv3.setText(c);
      conn.close();
          }
```

xml:

Why not all the information.
Just released the final data.
how to show all data.
how to edit xml Correct.
I do not know who to ask.

Comment: Can you describe your actual problem please?

Comment: program Show the last value. I do all that. The gridview to do this?.

Answer (score 0):

```
 while (rs.next()) 
      {
           tv1.setText(rs.getString("ItemDesc"));
           tv2.setText(rs.getString("Qty"));
           tv3.setText(rs.getString("NetPrice"));
     }
```

For every result you get, you set the contents of tv1, tv2 and tv3 to the contents of that result, **overwriting the previous contents**. If this is not what you want ( you didn't actually ask a question, so its hard to say, but I'm guessing your sparse *"Why not all the information"* means that you are complaining about seeing only the last entry?), you should not overwrite them.

What you can do is make a `String`, concatenate the new value to the current value, and then call `setText` once after the `while`?

Ok, you can do this. You might be better of using a `StringBuffer` btw, but that would need even more explaining...

```
String tv1S = "";
String tv2S = "";
String tv3S = "";

 while (rs.next()) {
      tv1S += rs.getString("ItemDesc"));
      tv2S += rs.getString("Qty"));
      tv3S += rs.getString("NetPrice"));
 }
 tv1.setText(tv1S);
 tv2.setText(tv2S);
 tv3.setText(tv3S);
```

Now you also will need some spacing and stuff like that, but I'm not going to write all for you, this should be enough to figure it out....

Comment: I have no clue what you want with that. Add it to your "question" if you think it helps, but it looks just like your XML, and it doens't change a thing about my answer.

Comment: For what? for making a string? You can find that out, can't you? You're doing that in the first couple of lines of your code for yourself. You do understand what the problem is, I hope? YOu're overwriting the value again and again. Now the only other thing you need to do is concatenate a string.. Did you look that up?

Comment: Well, there you go. Please tell me you have it from here? Otherwise it might be prudent to go back to Java basics first....

Comment: Thanks for the answer.May be a problem with xml layout.
I will try to solve the problem.